# How to Keep project files on different partation in ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I have following partitations

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                       63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          63G   16K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          63G  1.1M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                          63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/splocal00-root00  120G    60G  60G  50% /
/dev/sda1                     976M  355M  605M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/splocal00-tmp00   2.0G   11M  1.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/splocal01-data00  400G   33M  399G   1% /data00
tmpfs                          13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1002
```

Now i am creating projects `/home/user1/public_html`, `/home/user2/public_html`, `/home/user3/public_html`

i Would like to keep few images and datas on the `/dev/mapper/splocal01-data00 partation`.

How could i do that? for now these image files are stored into `/home/user1/images`. how to point these image files into `/dev/mapper/splocal01-data00` drive ?

Answer (score 0):

The .....data00 partition is mounted at /data00. That means that you can access it in your file manager by going to “other locations” and then choose computer. /data00 will appear as a folder called data00.

You can move data there via copy and paste using the file manager. Alternatively you can use the mv command to move or the cp command to copy using the terminal. The terminal makes it very easy to move all files or all files that match a condition in one operation.

When you create new files you should be able to save them by navigating to the /data00 folder using the save dialogue of the application you are using.

You might need to change the ownership of the /data00 folder and subfolders with the chown command. It’s easy to google for examples of these commands if you need them